# Swift. How to return a function from a closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a question regarding closure

```
function AA(){
     localPlayer.authenticateHandler{
       //…
       if trigger {
           retrun
       }
     }

     dosomething()
}
```

In the above code,
I want to write a code that wants to return to the `AA()` function when the `trigger` is satisfied in the authenticateHandler closure that is called by an asynchronous callback.

The result of the code above is
When `trigger` occurs, only the closure is returned and the `dosomething()` method is executed below.

Is there any way
I have short English skills, but thank you for your help.

Comment: So do you simply want to execute `dosomething()` after trigger is true, or do you want to wait in function `AA` until trigger is `true`? And what should happen if trigger never becomes `true`?

Comment: 1. I want to wait in `localPlayer.authenticateHandler` until trigger is `true`
2. call function `dosomething()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure does not support return statement. Instead use completion block inside main thread to perform the task:

i.e

```
function AA( completion: @escaping (Result<[Return Type], Error>) -> Void) {
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler{
        //…
        if trigger {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(//Whatever Return Value)
            }
        }
        dosomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: Closure does support return statements, but they return from the closure, not from the containing method.

Answer (score 0):

**Closure does not support return statement.**

Do it this way.
here i used string comparison to show how completion block will work.

```
    func call() {
        compareString(str1: "hey", str2: "hey") { isMatch in
            if isMatch! { //Trigger
                self.doSomething()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func compareString(str1:String,str2:String,completion:@escaping ((Bool?) -> Void)) {
        if str1 == str2 {
            completion(true)
        }else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
    
    func doSomething() {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t work that way. A synchronous function can’t wait for the result of an asynchronous function. Give AA a callback closure and call it when authenticateHandler returns.